# Storing safely files in the cloud - what is the current state of the art encrpytion method for it?

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-cracking, cloud-storage

What is considered as safe method to store files in the cloud currently and in the future (quantums) so that no potential hacker could open the file? Which current encryption methods to use for it to not being brute forced?

Thanks

Comment: The encryption method depends on your requirements, for example if you need random access or is file by file sufficient. I find it more important to think about where and how to store the keys. They shouldn’t be in the cloud.

Comment: @not2savvy, thanks. And can you please suggest a secure method/tool to encrypt a file, given this intention: Storing a file in Google Drive (eg a zip file) in a way, that when you get hacked, anyone will fail to open that zip file (even when they apply the most advanced current tech+quantum)? And not random access needed. It should not be able to open/write/edit/read the file without password/key.

Comment: It’s difficult, if not impossible, to speak for the future. AFAIK, it’s not yet clear what quantum computers could actually do in practice. Also, it’s not foreseeable if and when vulnerabilities in existing methods will be found.

Comment: @not2savvy, makes sense thx. Ignore the quantum future part. What method/tool would you from the current steate of the art, recommend me for my above intention?

Comment: Still not enough information. But gpg may be a good start in one way or the other.